Using local basemaps in a QField Cloud project
I am trying to find out if it is possible to set up a QField Cloud project that uses a large basemap I have locally saved to the mobile device and my PC.
The data collection layers should be synced via the QField Cloud, while the basemap is accessed locally. I am using QGIS 3.34 and the newest QField App version for Android.
I have seen the short info on this topic here in the documentation but I do not understand which localized path needs to be entered and how I then get the basemap into the project on the device.
